# Remove elements of a list with respect to elements of another list it R

Tags: r, list, indexing

So I have this df:

```
df <- read.csv("data_Marriages.csv")
```

And these two lists taken from df:

```
month_ins <- df$month_ins
city_ins <- df$city_ins
```

What I want is to remove from both the data respecting to the city `"Guayaquil"`, so for `city_insc` it is easier:

```
city_insc_NG <- city_insc[city_insc != "Guayaquil"]
```

because that list holds the names of the cities, but it is different when you try with `month_ins` how do I know which one belongs to "Guayaquil" and which one doesn't.

So I tried with a for loop, and didn't work either:

```
j = 1
for( i in city_ins){
   if(i == "Guayaquil"){
      city_ins[i] <- NULL
      month_ins[j] <- NULL
   }
   j = j + 1    
}
```

So... **How may I delete the elements in `month_ins` with respect to the positions in `city_ins`that holds `"Guayaquil"`in it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove values from `month_ins` in a similar fashion.

```
mont_ins_NG <- month_ins[city_insc != "Guayaquil"]
```

Or instead of vector subset from dataframe :

```
month_ins <- df$month_ins[df$city_insc != "Guayaquil"]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `with`

```
month_ins <- with(df, month_ins[city_insc != "Guayaquil"])
```